# Angular : using ngFor in a Table

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Please assist . I have the following table in [stackblitz](https://angular-mqkabz.stackblitz.io/) or [stackblitz 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqkabz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). The component of the table is as follows :

```
export class AppComponent {
   gender = [
      { id: 1, value : 'Female' },
      { id: 2, value : 'Male' }
    ];

   age = [
    { id: 1, value: 'Adults' },
    { id: 2, value: 'Children' },
    { id: 3, value: 'Creatures' },
    { id: 5, value: 'Youth' }
    ];

  color = [
    { id: 1, value: 'Black' },
    { id: 2, value: 'White' },
    { id: 3, value: 'Brown' },
  ];
}
```

The View of the table is as follows :

```
      <div *ngFor="let gender of gender; let g = index;">
        <table class="table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span>{{gender.value}}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table class="table-bordered">
                <tr *ngIf="g === 0">
                  <td>Age</td>
                  <td *ngFor="let color of color; let r = index;">{{ color.value }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngFor="let age of age; let a = index;">
                  <td>{{ age.value }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input [id]="" type="text" #black />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input [id]="" type="text" #white />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input [id]="" type="text" #brown/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```

I can get data from the view to the component using ViewChildren like `@ViewChildren(brown) brown: QueryList<elementRef>;` since i added `#brown`. According to angular doc using ElementRef can result to some security risks.

Question:
How can get data from component to view when i have such a table and is ther a better way to get data from the view to the component without using ViewChildren or ViewChild ?

If i have to introduce reactive forms to the table how can i implement it ?

Your help is much appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I managed to get your code working. I had to use ReactiveForms.
Here is the link https://angular-multiple-forms.stackblitz.io. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiple-forms?file=src%2Fpolyfills.ts
Here is the code itself.

**app.module.ts**

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms' ;

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
   beneficiary: any[];
   validationForm:any;
   gender = [
      { id: 1, value : 'Female' },
      { id: 2, value : 'Male' }
    ];

  age = [
    { id: 1, value: 'Adults' },
    { id: 2, value: 'Children (6-17)' },
    { id: 3, value: 'Creatures' },
    {
      id: 4,
      value: 'Early Childhood (0-5)'
    },
    { id: 5, value: 'Youth (18-35)' }
  ];

  color = [
    { id: 1, value: 'Black' },
    { id: 2, value: 'White' },
    { id: 3, value: 'Brown' },
  ];

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

 ngOnInit() {
  this.validationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  items: this.formBuilder.array(
    [this.buildForm()],
  )});
  this.initForm();
 }

 public initForm(): void{
  let formsCount = this.gender.length * this.age.length;
  for (let i= 1; i < formsCount; i++){
    this.validationForm.get('items').push(this.buildForm())
  }
 }

 public buildForm(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    black: this.formBuilder.control({value:'Me',disabled: false}, 
   [Validators.required]),
    white: this.formBuilder.control({value:'You',disabled: false}, [Validators.required]),
    brown: this.formBuilder.control({value:'Her',disabled: false}, 
   [Validators.required])
  });
 }

 public onSubmit(): void{
  let formData = this.validationForm.value.items;
  console.log(formData);
 }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
          <div *ngFor="let gender of gender; let g = index;">
        <table class="table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span>{{gender.value}}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table class="table-bordered">
                <tr *ngIf="g === 0">
                  <td>Age</td>
                  <td *ngFor="let color of color; let r = index;">{{ color.value }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngFor="let age of age; let a = index;">
                  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="validationForm">
                    <fieldset formArrayName="items">
                      <div class="form-group" [formGroup]="validationForm.get('items').controls[a]">
                      <td>{{ age.value }}</td>
                      <td>
                        <input formControlName="black" [id]="" type="text"/>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input formControlName="white" [id]="" type="text"/>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input formControlName="brown" [id]="" type="text"/>
                      </td>
                      </div>
                    </fieldset>
                  </form>

                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <button (click)="onSubmit()" type="button">Submit</button>
      </div>
```

Comment: managed to view the code. does that mean i have to add a Submit button inside the table to execute the onSubmit function

Comment: Thank you for the code, now the question is how can i get the data back to the view. lets say i want do a preview( or getting data from the database using http).

Comment: What do you exactly plan to do ? If you are trying to populate the form with data it is simple. In the buildForm() function you just add that value to the **value** attribute

Comment: You may add a submit button or not. It depends only on what you are planning to do. It two way binding so that data will always be the latest update.

Comment: Thanks for the response and update,  is the a way to make  the value `me`  not to repeat to all  black formControlName inputs but show  to one input either  the `Creatures` or `Youth` row.  The reasoning i'm asking is the user will capture the data and might not  add data to all inputs , so i wanted to add a save as draft button, then later depending what a user has added the form should populate the data  and allow the user to continue...don't know if its possible when i have such table.

Comment: Yeah sure you can. You can save the data in the localStorage and before showing the form you retrieve it. Or you just can save it inside a database and then get it from that DataBase. Lets me update the code.

Comment: I updated the code on stackblitz but i am not able to finish. You can continue and update according to your specifications. I used localStorage for example purpose. You must not use it for Prod application. But the idea is already emplemented

Comment: can you paste the link, because the one above, i cant view the components can only see the table. thank you.